# Google App Script debugger doesn't stop reliably at breakpoint

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I have a problem with the Google App Script debugger.

When I run my script in debug mode, it is correctly stopped at breakpoint on the first loop of my 'for loop'. But when I click the Play button (of the debugger) to continue to the next loop, the variables are not changed in the debugger window (the window that shows the variables values), as if the debugger remained blocked on the breakpoint. But actually, as the work done by my script on the next loops is done, I can see that the script actually didn't remain blocked on the breakpoint.

So, the debugger gives the feeling to be blocked on breakpoint (without possibility to continue the script on the next loops) even if it is not the case.

Anybody had this issue ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Would it be possible to share the script / code so we could test this and then share our insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There are a couple of reports on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Problem during Debug: Variable doesn't grow linearly but skip some values](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138131875)
- [Array Error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140362968)

Google does seem to know about this issue but if it's causing problems you can file your own bug about it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=329832&template=1028365).

You can also hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.